# ListView in a listview

Tags: java, android

I have listview in a listview on scrolling the inner listview content goes empty ,i am getting tags still getting problem, so to save the data i saved it list values in hasmap and getting from there.  but one list value is saved not other ,any one please give me clue or solution how to get the value from "finish data list"  as geting "unit" from "item" list and "feet" from "finish" data list  or any other problem in my below code
[image: getting unit from one list and feet from other Able to save unit value but on scrolling [feet] goes empty]

[image: on scrolling feet goes empty]

```
public class ViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private int lastExpandedGroupPosition;
private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<String> groupItems;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> childItems;
public int childCount = 0;
private Context context;
private List<List<String>> firstLevelItems;
HashMap<String, List<String>> firstLevelItems1;
private List<String> endData;
private HashMap<String, String> endHashmap;
private List<List<String>> finishData;
private int finishDataPosition;
private List<String> photos;
private int lengthCounter;
private int someCounter;


public ViewAdapter(Context context, ExpandableListView listView, List<String> groupItems) {
    if (listView != null)
        expandableListView = listView;
    if (context != null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (groupItems != null && !groupItems.isEmpty())
        this.groupItems = groupItems;
    childItems = new HashMap<>();
    firstLevelItems1 = new HashMap<>();
    firstLevelItems = new ArrayList<>();
    endData = new ArrayList<>();
    endHashmap = new HashMap<>();
    finishData = new ArrayList<>();
    photos = new ArrayList<>();
    this.context = context;
    ImageLoaderInit(context);
    lengthCounter = 0;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groupItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return childCount;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;


    ViewHolder vh = null;
    ;
    if (view == null) {
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_main_group_item, parent, false);
        vh.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_main_group_title);
        vh.arrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_main_group_arrow);
        view.setTag(vh);
    } else
        vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    if (isExpanded) {
        view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
        vh.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_down_10);
    } else {
        view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 15);
    }
    vh.title.setText(groupItems.get(groupPosition));

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    ViewHolder vh = null;
    if (view == null) {
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_main_child_item, parent, false);
        vh.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_main_child_item);


        vh.photoLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.view_main_child_bottom_layout);
        vh.firstLevelItemsLV = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_main_child_first_level_items);
       /* if (childPosition < childCount - 1) {
            vh.photoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else*/ {
            vh.firstPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_main_first_photo);

            vh.secondPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_main_second_photo);

            vh.thirdPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.view_main_third_photo);

            vh.thirdPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.default1);
            vh.secondPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.default1);
            vh.firstPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.default1);
        }
        view.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    if (childItems.get(groupPosition + "") != null && !childItems.get(groupPosition + "").isEmpty()) {
        String s = "• " + childItems.get(groupPosition + "").get(childPosition) + " :";
        vh.title.setText(s);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < firstLevelItems.get(childPosition).size(); i++) {
        if (finishData.size() > (lengthCounter)) {
            if (finishData.get(lengthCounter).size() > someCounter) {
                someCounter = finishData.get(lengthCounter).size() + 1;
            }
        } else
            // someCounter = finishData.get(finishData.get(lengthCounter).size()-1).size();
            /*{
                 {

           }

        }*/lengthCounter++;
    }
    int i = firstLevelItems.get(childPosition).size();
    Log.i("size ", i + "");
    //  someCounter= finishData.get(finishDataPosition).size()+2;
    Log.e("LENGTH", "Child: " + lengthCounter);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    float oneItemDp1 = display.getHeight();
    float oneItemDp = oneItemDp1 / 65;
    // float oneItemDp = 40 / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int heighy = (int) oneItemDp * (firstLevelItems.get(childPosition).size() +
            i + 1);
    vh.firstLevelItemsLV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, heighy
    ));
    someCounter = 0;//  by me
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) vh.firstLevelItemsLV.getLayoutParams();
    mlp.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);
    FirstLevelAdapter firstAdapter = new FirstLevelAdapter(context, firstLevelItems.get(childPosition));
    vh.firstLevelItemsLV.setAdapter(firstAdapter);
    if (vh.firstPhoto != null) {
        vh.firstPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (photos.size() >= 1) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EnlargeImageActivity.class);
                    String photo1 = photos.get(0);
                    intent.putExtra("photo1", photo1);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "New image to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ;
            }
        });
    }
    if (vh.secondPhoto != null) {
        vh.secondPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (photos.size() >= 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EnlargeImageActivity.class);
                    String photo1 = photos.get(1);
                    intent.putExtra("photo1", photo1);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "New image to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ;
            }
        });
    }
    if (vh.thirdPhoto != null) {
        vh.thirdPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (photos.size() >= 3) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EnlargeImageActivity.class);
                    String photo1 = photos.get(2);
                    intent.putExtra("photo1", photo1);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "New image to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ;

                }

            }
        });
    }

    if (vh.firstPhoto != null) {
        if (photos.size() >= 1) {
            if (!this.photos.isEmpty()) {
                vh.firstPhoto.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + Uri.parse(this.photos.get(0)), vh.firstPhoto, imageOptions);
            }
        } else {

            vh.firstPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.default1);
        }
    }

    if (vh.secondPhoto != null) {
        if (photos.size() >= 2) {
            if (this.photos.size() > 1 && !this.photos.isEmpty()) {
                vh.secondPhoto.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + Uri.parse(this.photos.get(1)), vh.secondPhoto, imageOptions);
            }
        } else {
            //vh.secondPhoto.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_save));
            //vh.secondPhoto.setMaxHeight(100);
            vh.secondPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.default1);
        }
    }
    if (vh.thirdPhoto != null) {
        if (photos.size() >= 3) {
            if (this.photos.size() > 2 && !this.photos.isEmpty()) {
                vh.thirdPhoto.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + Uri.parse(this.photos.get(2)), vh.thirdPhoto, imageOptions);
            }
        } else {

            vh.thirdPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.default1);
        }
    }


    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(final int groupPosition) {
    if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
        expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
    }
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
}

public void setChildView(int groupPosition, List<String> childItems, List<List<String>> firstLevelItems,
                         List<String> endData, List<List<String>> photos) {
    if (childItems != null && !childItems.isEmpty()) {
        childCount = childItems.size();
        this.childItems.put(groupPosition + "", childItems);
    }
    if (firstLevelItems != null && !firstLevelItems.isEmpty()) {
        this.firstLevelItems.clear();
        this.firstLevelItems.addAll(firstLevelItems);
        //   firstLevelItems1.put(groupPosition + "", firstLevelItems);
    }
    if (endData != null && !endData.isEmpty()) {
        finishData.clear();
        finishDataPosition = 0;
        someCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < endData.size(); i++) {
            List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> splitedList = new ArrayList<>();
            tempList = Arrays.asList(endData.get(i).split("\\|"));
            for (int j = 0; j < tempList.size(); j++) {
                if (!tempList.get(j).contains("Other")) {
                    if (!tempList.get(j).contains("Comment Box")) {
                        splitedList.add(/*Arrays.asList(*/tempList.get(j)/*.split(":"))*/);
                    }
                }
            }
            finishData.add(splitedList);
        }
    }
    List<String> tempPhotoList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (photos != null && !photos.isEmpty()) {
        this.photos.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < photos.get(i).size(); x++) {
                tempPhotoList.addAll(Arrays.asList(photos.get(i).get(x).split("\\|")));
            }
        }
        List<String> photoBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String name : tempPhotoList) {
            if (name.contains(".ABCInventory")) {
                photoBuffer.add(name);
                Log.e("TAG", name);
            }
        }
        this.photos = photoBuffer;
    }
}

private class FirstLevelAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> items;
    private Context _context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private String firstLevel;
    private ModelData md;
    private String s1;
    HashMap<Integer, View> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, View>();

    public FirstLevelAdapter(Context context, List<String> objects) {
        if (objects != null) {
            items = objects;

        }

        _context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder vh=null;
        if (items != null && !items.isEmpty()) {
            firstLevelItems1.put(position + "", items);
        }

        if (convertView == null) {
            md = new ModelData();

       /*     if (hashMap.containsKey(position)) {
                return hashMap.get(position);
            }*/
            try {
                {
                    s1 = "• " + firstLevelItems1.get(position + "").get(position) + " :" ;

                    md.finalFirtstLevel = s1;
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_main_child_second_item, parent, false);
            vh.item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_second_item);
            vh.elements = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_third_level_items);
            // vh.item.setText(s);
            vh.item.setText(md.finalFirtstLevel);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
           /* hashMap.put(position, convertView);*/
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (finishData.size() > (finishDataPosition)) // by me
            if (finishData.get(finishDataPosition).size() < 2) {
                String[] split = finishData.get(finishDataPosition).get(0).split(":");
                for (int i = 0; i < finishData.get(finishDataPosition).size(); i++) {
                    Log.i("split value ", finishData.get(finishDataPosition).get(i) + split[1] + " finishDataPosition " + finishDataPosition);

                }

                if (split[1] != null && !split[1].isEmpty()) {
                    md = new ModelData();
                    String s = "• " + firstLevelItems1.get(position + "").get(position) + " :" + split[1];

                    md.finalFirtstLevel = s;

                    vh.item.setText(md.finalFirtstLevel);
                }

            } else {
                md = new ModelData();
                String s = "• " + firstLevelItems1.get(position + "").get(position) + " :" ;
                md.finalFirtstLevel1 = s;


                vh.item.setText(md.finalFirtstLevel1);

                float oneItemDp = 10 / _context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                Log.e("LENGTH", "Adapter: " + lengthCounter);
                vh.elements.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        (int) oneItemDp * someCounter));
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) vh.elements
                        .getLayoutParams();
                mlp.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 0);
                //  vh.elements.setAdapter(new FinishDataAdapter(finishData.get(finishDataPosition)));
            }
        finishDataPosition++;

        return convertView;
    }

    ;

    public class ModelData {

        public String finalFirtstLevel = "";
        public String finalFirtstLevel1 = "";
    }
}

private class FinishDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> items;

    public FinishDataAdapter(List<String> objects) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        items = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_main_child_finish_item, parent, false);
        TextView item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.child_finish_item);
        item.setText("• " + items.get(position));
        return view;
    }
}

private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private DisplayImageOptions imageOptions;

private void ImageLoaderInit(Context context) {
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
            .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(10 * 1024 * 1024))
            .memoryCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
            .memoryCacheSizePercentage(20)
            .diskCacheSize(300 * 1024 * 1024)
            .diskCacheFileCount(375)
            .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
            .build();

    imageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.default1)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
            .delayBeforeLoading(0)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer())
            .handler(new Handler())
            .build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView arrow = null;
    LinearLayout photoLayout;
    ListView firstLevelItemsLV;
    TextView title = null;
    TextView title1 = null;
    ImageView firstPhoto;
    ImageView secondPhoto;
    TextView item;
    ImageView thirdPhoto;
    ListView elements;
}
```

}

Comment: hi its better to use table view inside listview according to snaps.

Comment: Why not a 3 level ExpandableListView?

Comment: @frank you are right but i have to change much of my code for that, i am getting problem in just saving  " String s = "• " + firstLevelItems1.get(position + "").get(position) + " :" + split[1]" this string accoding to position of my adapter as it changing with "finishposition" not with position of adapter.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do (haven't totally got it) I assume `getView()` is the wrong place to do it, especially as it will be getting called multiple times and without a strict order by the android system. Please try to explain what you want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: @Capricorn when a view goes out of visibility on scrolling that view goes completely empty  ,that "unit : feet" not seen again. i just manage to save "unit " or "color" and "type" using hash map.